# Trouble with Importing Java Libraries into a project with NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, importerror, java, import-libraries

I am having some issues with importing library which is needed to complete an assignment that I have been set.

I'm not sure if I have added the library to the project, but the classes from the library appear to be in the libraries section of the project.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGUqe.png

I added the libraries by right clicking on project1 and going to properties:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGUqe.png#1

However whenever I have "package project1" at the top of Project1.java I receive a message that MaInput - which is one of the classes in this library - is not recognised:

cannot find symbol:
        symbol: class MaInput

Whenever I take away "package project1" when trying to compile it reads:
Error: Could not find or load main class project1.Project1
Java Result: 1.

Comment: u r using cmd to compile ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access a class from default package from a named package and this is not allowed by the Java Specification.

So, in this case, create your assignment in the default package as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Sorry, I am extremely new to Java. What do you mean by create assignment in the default package?

Comment: don't use project1 for your classes Circle, Point ... put them in the default package